# How to not enter a route or an end point without logging in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, authorization

I am trying to build an application where I an end point , let's say `B`, I want to reach out only when user's credentials are valid. So, after I get the authentication done, I redirect the user to end point `B`. But to my suprise in my application I can directly enter the `B` end point without logging in. What should I do to avoid that? My application only has login, no logout and each time user wants to visit the end point `B` , I want the user to log in. Even if user try to go to that end point manually I want the user to redirect to login, What should I do?

Comment: plz provide us some code you've tried, there are JS code particularities that may change the possible solutions to your question. Ex: you may not taken in account the asynchronously particularity of javascript.

Comment: I would have, but the application is so large I couldn't share any instance of it, since it wouldn't make any sense. I just wanna know what is done in such cases?

Comment: In such cases, you debug the code, like using an IDE debug tool or console.log, using that, trace which lines of code are been executed, checking if the result of execution matches the expected, and also if the sequence of execution matches the expected sequence, as js execution allows a different line executed sequence than the written code.

Comment: Or, you may create a smaller project that represents/reproduces your case scenario, and provide us this sample so we can figure out what's not expected in the sample.

Comment: I was asking if I should be using any authentication/autherization methods like `jwt` or any such thing. Code is perfectly fine I think.

Comment: I think I understood your problem, I've tried my best to explain a solution for you in the answer in a comprehensive way, any doubts are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not allow access to a specific route http://localhost:3000/B, you can define the auth verification functions before the main function for that endpoint, and then break the function execution sequence by ending the request in the auth functions, not allowing the main function to be called.

More detailed explanation:

While defining the route (*LINE 27*) you can apply many functions that will be called sequentially, but if in one of these functions you finish the request (**req**) the next declared functions aren't going to be called, making the main function inaccessible;

When you receive a request in Express, you'll receive as the third argument a callback that will call the **next** function in the chain defined (*LINE 8, 17*)

Example of auth dealing using node|express:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const authentication = (req, res, next) => {
  // todo verify authentication
  if (true) {
    next() // LINE 8
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message: 'not authenticated'}) // LINE 10
  }
}

const authorization = (req, res, next) => {
  // todo verify authorization
  if (true) {
    next() // LINE 17
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message: 'not authorized'}) // LINE 19
  }
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.post('/login', (req, res) => res.send({token: 'magic-jwt-token'}))

app.get('/B', authentication, authorization, (req, res) => res.send('B works!')) // LINE 27

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```